# How to find relevant log file to report crashes?

Tags: bug-reporting

In last two days, I experienced two crushes of Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit (something that was not happening with Ubuntu 14.10). I updated to Ubuntu 15.04 via software updater.

The first crush happened when I wanted to start Viber. I clicked on icon in Ubuntu dashboard... and session was restarted... I logged in again and system was working but CPU usage was kept at 30% constantly. How can I find relevant log file to report the bug?

Second bug happened yesterday. I wanted to shut down the computer and it never shut down. Screen was black but laptop indicators did not turn off. How can I find relevant log file to report the bug?

And where to submit these bugs when log files are found?

Theis is recent dmesg output:

```
[ 1697.914255] gdbus[1723]: segfault at 300000001 ip 00007f7cc443c6fa sp 00007f7cc20ecb38 error 4 in libc-2.21.so[7f7cc43b1000+1c0000]

[13908.183991] soffice.bin[8153]: segfault at f0 ip 00007ffb3239d357 sp 00007ffefa010500 error 4 in libmergedlo.so[7ffb31296000+3a29000]

[14483.243270] compiz[1847]: segfault at 20 ip 00007f7ed669a29d sp 00007ffd270557f0 error 4 in libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.3600.8[7f7ed668b000+14000]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can report the bugs in [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu). Also read the [ReportingBugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) wiki to know more about bug reporting (including how to generate log files).